# C - Matrix multiplication is slow in a separate function but very fast in main

Tags: c, optimization, matrix-multiplication

I'm optimizing a matrix multiplication program in C. Currently my code is like this:

First I have a struct for matrix:

```
typedef struct
{
    float ** element;
} matrix;
```

Then I wrote a matrix multiplication routine and optimize it by transposing the second matrix and using simd:

```
void mulMatrices(matrix a, matrix b, matrix result)
{

    int i, j, k;
    long long before, after;

    before = wall_clock_time();

    transpose_matrix(&b);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            __m128 vresult = _mm_setzero_ps();
            for(k = 0; k < size; k += 4)
            {
                vresult = _mm_add_ps(vresult, _mm_mul_ps(_mm_load_ps(&(a.element[i][k])), _mm_load_ps(&(b.element[j][k]))));
            }
            result.element[i][j] = vresult[0] + vresult[1] + vresult[2] + vresult[3];
        }

    after = wall_clock_time();
}
```

At last I wrote a worker function to initialize the matrices and call the multiplication function

```
void work()
{
    matrix a, b, result;

    // Initialise matrices

    // Perform sequential matrix multiplication
    mulMatrices(a, b, result);

    // Print the result matrix
    //print_matrix(result);

}
```

My main function looks like:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{   
    // Multiply the matrices
    work();
    return 0;
}
```

I could achieve quite satisfying result with these things already. However I found out that if I streamline every thing and move all of the code into the main function, it will be more than 100 times faster. The matrices are at least 1024 * 1024 in size. I guess there is something to do with the call stack but I don't understand it. Could someone explain. Thanks

Comment: You call `mm` not `mulMatrices` in your `main`. And you should learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: What is the difference between `mm` and `mulMatrices`?

Comment: I'd expect `mulMatrices()` to look more like `mulMatrices(matrix *a, matrix *b, matrix *result)`.  Pass the address, not value.

Comment: have you tried with declaring pointers to your data structure in the main and pass these pointers in functions?

Comment: Sorry, I made some changes in the code so it is indeed mulMatrices in work. I did try passing as pointers. I also tried global variables but as soon as the result becomes visible outside the mulMatrices function, the speed will becomes slow.

Comment: Can you post your main program (the not-inlined one, with the function call)?

Comment: Sure, edited with the main function appended to the snippets. It's actually very simple with a single call to work.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely running into an [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_%28computing%29) issue. Basically when editing values through pointers, the compiler doesn't know if you've modified something that it has already read, so it will have to reread the values from memory every time.

Here is a whitepaper that describes the problem: ftp://ftp.sgi.com/sgi/audio/audio.apps/dev/aliasing.html

By moving all the code directly into your main, you've removed the aliases, thus improving the performance drastically.

Comment: This looks reasonable. I tried adding __restrict keyword but it didn't work. For modularity, I have to keep the functions. Is there any workaround for this problem?